# Как узнать о вызове метода?

Tags: c#, события, методы, рефлексия

Допустим есть следующий класс

```
class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SayHello();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Как другой класс может быть осведомлен о вызове метода SayHello без внесения изменений в этот?
Наверное рефлексией можно добиться этого? Но поиск по msdn ничего похожего не выдал

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что рефлексией добиться этого нельзя.

Рефлексия не панацея от всех болезней.

Нет, конечно вы можете вызвать метод, а потом рефлексией поставить метку в поле класса, но тем самым вы нарушите внутреннее состояние.

Не понимаю, зачем вам это могло понадобится...

Вы можете сделать обертку для класса-посредника и через него дергать свой класс, а сам посредник будет делать отметки, что метод вызывался.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш класс не закрытый, и от него можно наследоваться, то поступим так, наследуемся от этого класса, переопределим настоящий метод `SayHello` указав компилятору ключевое слово `new` в методе `SayHello` класса-наследника. Напишем простой `delegate` *(можно использовать `Action`)* и `event`, а так же метод который будет производить вызов делегата *(подробнее читайте о коллбэках c#)*. Далее, подпишемся на созданный ивент, и будем передавать сообщение в консоль которое будет приходить от класса наследника *(В данном примере используется `Trace` в тестовых классах)*.

Результат работы: https://ideone.com/PiWlQU

```
public class Example
{
    public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

public class DeviredExample : Example
{
    public delegate void MethodCall(object sender, string message);

    public event MethodCall CallMethod;
    protected virtual void OnCallMethod(string message, Action callback)
    {
        callback?.Invoke();
        CallMethod?.Invoke(this, message);
    }

    public new void SayHello()
    {
        OnCallMethod("Say hello called", () => base.SayHello());
    }
}
```

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    DeviredExample d = new DeviredExample();

    int i = 0;

    d.CallMethod += (sender, message) =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(message);
        i = 1;
    };

    d.SayHello();
    if (i != 0)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
        return;
    }

    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Результат теста:

```
Tests (1 test) [0:00.989] Success
 yami.ui.tests (1 test) [0:00.989] Success
  yami.ui.tests.Services (1 test) [0:00.989] Success
   SettingsModelTest (1 test) [0:00.989] Success
    Test [0:00.989] Success


Трассировка отладки:
Hello
Say hello called
```

Comment: статичный метод, как в примере, нельзя переопределять

Comment: @Grundy: В ответе не шла речь о статических методах.

Comment: А в вопросе пример как раз с ними